# Reloading a parents iframe from a child

Tags: iframe, target

I have two iframes on my page, frameOne and frameTwo.
I'm trying to refresh/reload frameOne from a script running in frameTwo.

```
function reload(){
  srcLink = parent.document.getElementById('frameOne').src;
  parent.document.getElementById('frameOne').src=srcLink;
}
```

This works but it refreshes to the initial value of the iframe.
IE:
If the parent page loaded with that iframe's src set to 'google.com' but then changed to (due to a user action) 'yahoo.com' my code will refresh that page to 'google.com', the link it was set to when the page was loaded. I would like to take into account the change of link and refresh that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from `frames[1]` *(the 2<sup>nd</sup> `iframe` page)*:

```
function changeFrameSrc(becauseURL, changeURL){
  var bc = new RegExp(becauseURL, 'i');
  if(bc.test(location)){
    parent.frames[0].src = changeURL;
  }
}
```